# C# are value types in a delegate different to those in the parent method

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

Consider the below block of code:

```
int noThreads = noProcessors - 1;
var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(noThreads);
if (noThreads == 0)
    noThreads = 1;

float blockSize = (float)jobList.Count / noThreads;

int startIndex, stopIndex;
for (int i = 0; i < noThreads; i++)
{
    startIndex = i * (int)blockSize;
    stopIndex = (i + 1) * (int)blockSize;
    if (i == noThreads - 1)
        stopIndex = jobList.Count;

    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        for (int j = startIndex; j < stopIndex; j++)
        {
            CreateJobAndAddToCollection(jobs[j], jobList, j);
        }

        countdownEvent.Signal();
    }).Start();                
}


countdownEvent.Wait();
```

I want to know whether the variables startIndex and stopIndex within the delegate point to the same location as their namesakes outside the delegate. From my testing I think they do, which surprises me as they are value types, and I would have thought that the code inside the delegate would be considered a separate method.
Apologies if this has been asked before, I haven't been able to find any other information about it.

Comment: The *variables* within the delegate are the same as the variables in the enclosing method. This is as true for value types as it is for reference types.

Comment: I believe they do indeed refer to the same objects since they're not passed as parameters to a method.  If you need them to be different, I'd create a method from the anonymous function and pass them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know whether the variables startIndex and stopIndex within the delegate point to the same location as their namesakes outside the delegate.

Yes, they do. The variables themselves are captured - changes made within the delegate will be visible outside the delegate, and vice versa.

However, this is only a problem because you've declared `startIndex` and `stopIndex` *outside* the loop. If you declare them *inside* the loop, each iteration will use a separate pair of variables.

```
for (int i = 0; i < noThreads; i++)
{
    int startIndex = i * (int)blockSize;
    int stopIndex = (i + 1) * (int)blockSize;
    // Code as before
}
```

Each delegate will now capture a separate `startIndex` and `stopIndex` pair, and the rest of the code in the loop doesn't modify those variables, so you'll be "safe". In other words, if your loop code contained:

startIndex++;
   stopIndex++;

at the end, then the delegate would still see those changes (assuming the new thread actually executed the delegate after the end of the iteration...) But the new pair of variables on the *next* iteration of the loop will be entirely independent from this iteration.

Avoiding threads, here's a simple example to show all this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int outerCounter = 0;
        var actions = new List<Action>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            outerCounter = i * 10;
            int innerCounter = i * 10;
            // Using an anonymous method here as per question;
            // you'd see the same behaviour with a lambda expression.
            actions.Add(delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", outerCounter, innerCounter);
            });

            innerCounter++;
        }

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
40: 1
40: 11
40: 21
40: 31
40: 41
```

This shows:

- All delegates are using the same `outerCounter` variable, which has a value of 40 at the end of the `for` loop.
- Each delegate is using its own `innerCounter` variable, which has a value of `i * 10` when the delegate is *created*, but `i * 10 + 1` by the time the delegate is *executed* due to the `innerCounter++` line.

Comment: "If you declare them inside the loop, each iteration will use a separate pair of variables:" But this won´t change the already said about the use of those variables within the delegate. Changes within the delegate will still affect those variables (vice versa).

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Indeed - but the OP won't see the problem he's currently seeing. Will clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

They are passed by reference to the delegate method.

Comment: I think this is a very confusing way of describing it - I wouldn't use any wording that uses "passing" for this, personally. I think it's better to use the terminology of the specification, in terms of a variable being captured.